# Firebase Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to do a rule that allows read, only the docs that don't have isRemoved = true

"isRemoved" is a boolean field

I've tried something like that but it blocks the read to all docs.

```
match /Users/{User_Id}/Sessions/{Sessions_Id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == User_Id && ( !resource.data.isRemoved.exists || resource.data.isRemoved != 'true');
}
```

How it should be written correctly?

Comment: Isn’t it exist instead of exits?

Comment: tried "exist"
and still all docs blocked to read

Comment: I meant exists!

Comment: tried "exists" but it's didn't resolve it.

Comment: Try ... || !resource.data.isRemoved?

Comment: Can you also include the code you are using to (try to) read? And possibly include all the different rules you have tried so far.

Comment: By this doc
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource

If the key doesn't exist it an error.

so how I can make a security rule that checks if some key exists?